WPA(2/3, etc) brute force tool for AOSP distributions
Request

I'm looking for a F(L)OSS application (ideally prepackaged as an .APK installation file, so that I don't have to deal with CI) for version 14 of the Android OS, which provides the ability to access WPA3 (ideally SAE Transition Mode too)-secured 802.11 networks.
Rationale

The reason is that I have a lot of APs to test the security of, and I don't have a laptop. Being able to utilize one of my myriad Android devices instead would be seriously convenient, even if the functionality that the application provides is relatively basic in comparison to something available for Windows 11 or Fedora 40, for instance.
Unacceptable Examples




Location (as URI)
Positive Attributes
Negative Attributes




com.m24apps.wifimanager
The sole option available via the Play Store.
Includes myriad irrelevant and dubious functionality, and appears to be proprietary.


Hijacker-release-v1.5-beta.12.apk from github.com/chrisk44/Hijacker
The sole option available via the Kali F-Droid repository, and probably for good reason - it appears to be quite powerful.
Unmaintained and archived repository.



Though, I'll be glad for any responses which contain answers like these examples if they're well-substantiated. I'm thankful for all responses, really.
